# Emacs: make portion of buffer readonly

Tags: emacs

I sometimes edit files in `emacs` where portions of the file are 
documentation or something else that shouldn't be edited, and another 
portions are "play areas" where I'm free to edit and create new text.

Question: can I make a *portion* of an emacs buffer readonly?

The simplest example would be making lines 1-100 readonly (for 
example). A more complex example (similar to emacs bookmarks) would be 
to make all text between `[readonly]` and `[/readonly]` uneditable.

I googled this, but couldn't find anything useful.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

Yes, you can make a portion of a buffer read-only using text properties.  The code below defines two new commands `make-region-read-only` and `make-region-read-write` that affect the region between point and mark.  Put the code in your .emacs file to make the commands available via <kbd>Meta-x</kbd>.

```
(defun make-region-read-only (start end)
  (interactive "*r")
  (let ((inhibit-read-only t))
    (put-text-property start end 'read-only t)))

(defun make-region-read-write (start end)
  (interactive "*r")
  (let ((inhibit-read-only t))
    (put-text-property start end 'read-only nil)))
```